# What is the basic difference between differentiable, analytic and holomorphic function?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

The function $f(z)$ is said to be analytic at $z_0$ if its derivative exists at each point $z$ in some neighborhood of $z_0$, and the function is said to be differentiable if its derivative exist at each point in its domain.
So whats the difference?

Comment: I think you mean "differentiable" not "differential."

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: The terms each have their own meaning -- but it turns out that the complex derivative has the surprising property that in this special case, they turn out to be equivalent.

Comment: You forgot "entire" which also falls in this question, so now we have 4 (!!) quasi synonymous terms.

Answer (score 3):

Holomorphic functions are complex functions, analytic functions are not necessarily complex.

Both, holomorphic and analytic functions, are infinitely continuous differentiable. But a differentiable functions is not necessarily infinitely differentiable, moreover: an infinitely differentiable function is not necessarily analytic or holomorphic.

Comment: This means that analytic functions are complex and real functions, Holomorphic functions are complex, and differentiable functions are real functions? :)

Comment: @user2129579 No, differentiable functions can be real or complex.

Comment: Ok.  Can I say that differentiable functions are finitely or infinitely differentiable, and analytic functions are always infinitely differentiable?

Comment: @user2129579 yes but I recommend that you take a book of analysis to learn this topic properly.

Answer (score -2):

Take $f(z) = z^2 \cdot 1_{\mathbb Q}$. This function is not holomorphic but it is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: $1_{\mathbb Q}(z) = 1$ if $z \in \mathbb Q$ and $0$ else.

Comment: (Another comment : holomorphic = analytic, but this is not an obvious theorem. This is normally done in a first course in complex analysis.)